# Gmote fails to install. Java problem?

Tags: java, remote

I am having problems installing the gmote server for linux (12.04 lts0 
java jre is installed (i think)

```
anton@anton-VGN-NW11S-T:~$ '/home/anton/Downloads/ 
GmoteServerLinux2.0.0/GmoteServer.sh' 
Starting GmoteServer 2.0 ... 
GmoteServer started. 
anton@anton-VGN-NW11S-T:~$ Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gmote/server/GmoteServerUiLinux 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUiLinux
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217) 
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321) 
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) 
Could not find the main class: org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUiLinux. 
Program will exit.
```

Is this a problem with the **tar.gz** file or is java not installed....
Thanks

Comment: could you edit the question to use `code` blocks (start and end with `) to make the console dump easier to read please

Comment: @jackweirdy I have edited already.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the program; you'd better try the support forums/ troubleshooting pages for the software itself.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to "sh Gmoteserver.sh", you must start it by

```
./GmoteServer.sh
```

in my case i made a File /usr/bin/GmoteServer (executable!) with content

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/lib/GmoteServerLinux2.0.0 && ./GmoteServer.sh
```

and i copied the whole Folder "GmoteServerLinux2.0.0" into /usr/lib. ("sudo nautilus")

The alternative script works not for me:

```
echo "Starting GmoteServer 2.0 ... " 
cd /home/USER/PATH-TO-GMOTE 
java -classpath bin:lib/jna.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.5.3.jar:lib/swing- 
worker-1.2.jar org.gmote.server.GmoteServerUiLinux & 
echo "GmoteServer started."
```

--> Didn't Work: swing-worker-1.2.jar not found.

(Source: Google Groups, "Matze")